# Amount of heat emitted from the Sun by radiation

Tags: mathematical-physics, reflection, radiation, thermal-radiation

Supposing that the condition of humidity and the temperature are the same. Concretely if in one place on Earth there is the same humidity, temperature, it is more hot in the first part of the summer when the Sun is closer and closer to the Zenith than to last part of the summer (21 June - 22 Sept).

**Question:**

> *Is it possible to prove, with mathematical formulas, the the heat $Q_{0}>Q$ ($Q_0$ is the heat of the first part of the summer) where $Q$ is the heat radiated by the Sun in the last part of the summer?*

Comment: what date is beginning and end of summer for you?

Comment: What does Snell’s Law have to do with this?

Comment: @G.Smith Hi, I have thinked of yes; or something with the radiation. If there is an incongruence, please, can you edit my question, also if my English language is it correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not truly understand your question, but don't forget that anywhere north or south of the tropics, (a) the Sun is higher in the sky during summer months, which means that the angle between its rays and the ground is more nearly square, and (b) the Sun is above the horizon for _more hours of the day._

Comment: @SolomonSlow My question is how to justify having the same temperature, humidity, heat perception is different?

Comment: @G.Smith Hi, I have improved my question.

Comment: You are asking for a very simple explanation of climate. There isn't one. It's complex.

Comment: @my2cts Do it exists a simple explanation (with particular hypotesis) with the inclination of the Sun's rays?

Answer (score 0):

Since 20 or 30  days before and after Summer Solstice the sun has the same angle to earth so you can not prove heat by the angle, Probably there are other weather conditions which determine temperature .

Comment: In the meantime, I thank you kindly for your kind answer.

Comment: Indeed, the Earth’s surface, including bodies of water and atmosphere, has enough heat capacity to delay peak heat by a month or two following the summer solstice (and minimum average temperatures are likewise delayed following the winter solstice).

Comment: Let's also mention convection, reflection, evaporation, closeness of open water, forest, mountains or desert etc. Etc.